# How to display short date from DateTime field in label?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a DateTime field in my SQL Server DB, and I would like to display just the date in short date form on a label in a WinForm (C#). I still get 06/01/2013 12:00:00, though, even when using:

```
label_date.Text = myDateTimeField.Date.ToString();
```

To extract the time for later use, I use:

```
label_time.Text = myDateTimeField.TimeOfDay.ToString();
```

and that works just fine.

Anyone know how to get the date out *alone*?

Comment: I'm amazed you took the time to post rather than a simple Google of "short date DateTime"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx):

```
label_date.Text = myDateTimeField.ToShortDateString();
```

Remarks:

> The value of the current DateTime object is formatted using the
>   pattern defined by the [DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern.aspx) property
>   associated with the current thread culture. The return value is
>   identical to the value returned by specifying the "d" standard
>   DateTime format string with the ToString(String) method.
>
> The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is
>   culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current
>   culture's [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) object. For example, for the en-US
>   culture, the standard short date pattern is "M/d/yyyy"; for the de-DE
>   culture, it is "dd.MM.yyyy"; for the ja-JP culture, it is "yyyy/M/d".
>   The specific format string on a particular computer can also be
>   customized so that it differs from the standard short date format
>   string.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I don't know why I didn't think of it! Thank you. -- Will accept your answer when it lets me in 10 minutes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

`string shortDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Change the *`yyyy-MM-dd`* format for the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

check the sequence of the date - month - year the input in sql is diffrent

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data annotation in model (or in ViewModel) class like follows:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DateOfExpiration { get; set; }
```